# Зачем нужен паттерн Адаптер?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Прошу прощения.Кто разобрался с этим паттерном прошу помощи.
Какое его назначение и где его можно применить  в PHP+mysql?

Comment: Вкратце: адаптер позволяет привести один интерфейс к другому для дальнейшего использования.

Comment: Совет №0. Если паттерн ну нужен - не применяйте.

Comment: пример в википедии шикарен:передается ссылка на объект и используются его свойства...интересно какое отношение оно имело к тому что там написано..Гениальный пример.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как было сказано выше, адаптер позволяет решить проблему несовместимости интерфейсов. Предположим, у вас есть два класса, не связанные общей иерархией наследования и не реализующие одних и тех же интерфейсов, что затрудняет их взаимодействие. В таком случае будет полезен некий класс-обертка, который реализует интерфейс первого класса и путем композиции включает в себя второй, методы которого могут быть вызваны в методах класса-обертки. Более содержательно об этом можно прочесть [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/85095/) и [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Да, и еще:

> Какое его назначение и где его можно применить в PHP+mysql

Если вы собрались применять паттерн только ради применения паттерна, то это очень глупая затея.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Product{  
    private $prix;  
    function __construct($prix){
        $this->prix = $prix; 
    } 
    function getPrix(){
        return $this->prix; 
    }
}

class ProductAdapter(Product $product, $discount){ 
        function getPrix(){
        return $this->product -> getPrix() - $discount; 
    } 
}

$product1 = new Product(1000); 
$product1-> getPrix (); 
$productDiscount = ProductAdapter($product1, 300); 
// цена со скидкой $productDiscount -> getPrix ();
```